# Change the background color of each section of the page when the user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change the background color of each section of the page when the user scrolls. The code works but I feel like it's too inefficient

```
var colors = ['blue','yellow','green','purple','brown'];
var myScope;
var sections = [$('#section1'),$('#section2'),$('#section3'),$('#section4'),$('#section5')];
var sectionTop = [$('#section1').offset().top, $('#section2').offset().top, $('#section3').offset().top, $('#section4').offset().top, $('#section5').offset().top];
var zeus;

$(window).scroll(function () {
myScope = $(window).scrollTop() + 300;

    if (myScope >= sectionTop[0]  && myScope < sectionTop[1]) {
    sections[0].css('background-color', colors[0]);
    } else {
    sections[0].css('background-color', 'white');
    };

    if (myScope >= sectionTop[1]  && myScope < sectionTop[2]) {
    sections[1].css('background-color', colors[1]);
    } else {
    sections[1].css('background-color', 'white');
    };

    if (myScope >= sectionTop[2]  && myScope < sectionTop[3]) {
    sections[2].css('background-color', colors[2]);
    } else {
    sections[2].css('background-color', 'white');
    };

    if (myScope >= sectionTop[3]  && myScope < sectionTop[4]) {
    sections[3].css('background-color', colors[3]);
    } else {
    sections[3].css('background-color', 'white');
    };

    if (myScope >= sectionTop[4] ) {
    sections[4].css('background-color', colors[4]);
    } else {
    sections[4].css('background-color', 'white');
    };

});
```

I also tried to replace all those "if" with a "for" loop but it doesn't work, it doesn't pop any errors or anything, it just doesn't work.

```
for (var i = 0; i < sections.length-1; i++) {
        var j = i++;
        if (myScope >= sectionTop[i] && myScope < sectionTop[j]) {
        sections[i].css('background-color', colors[i]);
        } else {
        sections[i].css('background-color', 'white');
        };
    };
```

Comment: Why do you need to change to color when scrolling? Can't you set it in advance?

Comment: I saw it on a website and thought it looked great so I wanted to try it. It also had a transition effect that I haven't added yet.

Comment: for selecting all the elements with an `id` that starts with `section` you can use `$('[id^="section"]')`

Comment: I came here to run your code but I couldn't . It would have been helpful to have some HTML to visualise what you are trying to achieve. FYI, Twitter bootstrap has a scrollspy plugin that achieves what I think you are aiming for http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_scrollspy.asp

Answer (score 1):

Heres your code slimmed down, the problem you were having with the loop was that you weren't getting `offset().top` of your `sectionTop[i]`.

```
var myScope = zeus = false;
var colors = ['blue','yellow','green','purple','brown'];
var sectionId = '#section';
var sections = 5;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
myScope = $(window).scrollTop() + 300;

for (var i = sections; i >= 0; i--) {
   var sid = i > 0 ? i : 1;
   var css = 'white';
   if(myScope >= $(sectionId + sid).offset().top 
   && myScope < $(sectionId + sid).offset().top) {
    css = colors[i];
   }

   $(sectionId + sid).css('background-color', css);
}

});
```

Comment: At least only read `$(sectionId + sid).offset().top` once